# Why does Estarossa have a different full counter than Meliodas?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

In the fight against Escanor,  Estarossa uses full counter that can only block physical attacks.

Why does Estarossa have a different full counter than Meliodas?

Answer (score 0):

Because it was not meant to be the same, Estarossa and Meliodas have different abilities. There is no reason for them to be the same. There has been no reason that I have seen for the powers that they have and if one can counter magic it makes sense another can counter physical attacks.

Comment: It's worth noting both of their abilities have the exact same name "Full Counter" (In Japanese: 全反撃) a name also shared with the ability of Meliodas' mentor, Chandler. Also for somewhat spoiler-y reasons surrounding Estarossa's origins there's a very deep association between Meliodas and Estarossa which (at least thematically) might explain why they possess mirrored versions of each other's signature ability